# Synchronize Arraylist as buffer seems missing some data caused by multi-thread inconsistency in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I intend to create a `ArrayList` as a buffer, and the code snippet is as follows:

```
//MyService.java 

private List<Record> buffer  = new ArrayList<>(600);

@Async
public void putRecord()   {
    counter++;
    buffer.add(createRecord(""+counter+"\n"));
    synchronized (buffer)   {
        if(buffer.size() >= 10) {
            sendDataToRemote(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
    }
}

//MyController.java

@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String test() {
    myService.putRecord();
    return "done";
}
```

When the buffer's size is greater than 10, send the data in batch to remote and clear the buffer. This code is in Spring Boot Framework, in order to not block the Restful API, `@Async` is applied so as to make it super responsive for front-end. But if I check the content sending to remote, the counter is not continuous all the time:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
...
```

so I think there must be some multi-thread problem. Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're adding data to the ArrayList before the `synchronized` block. `ArrayList` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Well, you access your list and modify it from multiple threads without synchronization. That shouldn't surprise you. Also, what's the point of initializing it with a capacity of 600 if it's suppose to contain at most 10 elements? Also, your counter isn't thread-safe either.

Comment: Should I use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to initial the list instead? @RealSkeptic

Comment: I'm wondering, if a thread is entering synchronized block, then other thread will stuck at `buffer.add`, right? So there shouldn't be a multi-thread inconsistency problem. @RealSkeptic

Comment: @JasonZhu: No, because you haven't put the `add` in the `synchronized` block. So the `add` doesn't participate in synchronization (doesn't wait until other threads are done with the `synchronized` block, and you have unsynchronized access to the list.

Comment: No, that's not how synchronization works. Any thread can execute non-synchronized blocks of code, even if another one is executing a synchronized block. You need to take a step back, and carefully study how this works.

Comment: Thanks man, then how to make the list and counter thread-safe? As said above to RealSkeptic, the other thread should block at `buffer.add` when there's one thread is in synchronized block right? @JBNizet

Comment: The `add` operation is not atomic. You can consider it as "add at the `size`'th place, update size". Then two threads can add to the same place because the first one hasn't done the `update size` part yet.

Comment: Every access to the list and to the counter must be synchronized, on the same lock. Multiple accesses that must be atomic (like add then clear) must also be in the same synchronized block.

Comment: Could u recommend a book for this thing? it's relatively new to me. Thanks !  @JBNizet

Comment: Java Concurrency in Practice, by Brian Goetz, is the bible.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone give me some idea?

If you need a thread-safe counter, the easiest option is `AtomicInteger` and it's `incrementAndGet` method.

```
counter++;
buffer.add(createRecord(""+counter+"\n")); // <-- at ths point, counter might have already been altered by another thread
```

Whenever you access (this includes reading) non-thread-safe mutable state, you must hold the corresponding lock.

```
buffer.add(createRecord(""+counter+"\n")); // <-- not thread-safe
synchronized (buffer)   {
    //[...]
}
```

Never do I/O while holding a lock, unless you really have to (you most likely don't). Manually unlocking/re-locking might help in theory, but ignore that for now.

```
synchronized (buffer)   {
    if(buffer.size() >= 10) {
        sendDataToRemote(buffer); // <-- blocks all other threads from accessing the buffer during send operation
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```

If you want "super responsive", decouple as much work as possible from the thread serving the request. Manually unlocking/re-locking will not help you here.

```
synchronized (buffer)   {
    if(buffer.size() >= 10) {
        sendDataToRemote(buffer); // <-- might be slow or run into a timeout, the client has to wait until this finishes
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```

What you want to do instead:

- `incrementAndGet` a counter value
- put that value and all data needed for `createRecord` into some holder object

  - alternatively, you can run `createRecord` in the request thread if it's fast enough
- place the holder object (or report) into a queue
- have another thread constantly poll that queue for new data, run `createRecord` if you haven't done so in the request thread
- have the polling thread send out records once it has collected the desired amount

That way, you can keep the code handling the reports single-threaded *and* have low response times for all requests.

> Could u recommend a book for this thing? it's relatively new to me. Thanks !

You can find everything you need in the `java.util.concurrent` package, take a look at the package overview for a start. Read about `Executor`s and how to use them, especially for more complex scenarios. Once you are ready to dig deeper into the subject, this is solid advice:

> Java Concurrency in Practice, by Brian Goetz, is the bible. – JB Nizet